# Swift - do-while loop unexpected error

Tags: xcode, swift, do-while

I am going through Apple's Swift Guide and I encountered an error in a do-while loop and I can't work out why Xcode throws the error.

This code is straight from the book:

```
let finalSquare = 25

var board2 = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0) //26 values (0 included)

board2[03] = +08; board2[06] = +11; board2[09] = +09; board2[10] = +02 //the ladders
board2[14] = -10; board2[19] = -11; board2[22] = -02; board2[24] = -08 //the snakes
var square2 = 0
var diceRoll2 = 0

do {
    square2 += board2[square2]
    if ++diceRoll2 == 7 { diceRoll2 = 1 }
    square2 += diceRoll2    
} while square2 < finalSquare
```

However I wish to move up a ladder or down a snake straight after I roll, so I did this:

```
do {
    if ++diceRoll2 == 7 { diceRoll2 = 1 }
    square2 += diceRoll2
    square2 += board2[square2]
} while square2 < finalSquare
```

This throws the error:

`Execution was interrupted, reason:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: which error and on which line?

Comment: I think it is because the `diceRoll2` could take the value over 25 which leaves the next line a 'square2' value over 25 which is the max value. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: The line `square2 += board2[square2]` with an error of EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: You should write that in your question, because it's relevant and without that info the question itself is incomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code:

```
do {
    square2 += board2[square2]
    if ++diceRoll2 == 7 { diceRoll2 = 1 }
    square2 += diceRoll2    
} while square2 < finalSquare
```

square2 is incremented, then its value is checked against `finalSquare`, causing the loop to end if it's greater than or equal to.

In your code instead:

```
do {
    if ++diceRoll2 == 7 { diceRoll2 = 1 }
    square2 += diceRoll2 // < incremented here
    square2 += board2[square2] // < exception here
} while square2 < finalSquare
```

you increment `square2` and then you use it to access the corresponding array element, but without checking whether it is behind the array bounds (that check is done after accessing the array, so useless in this case).

A quick patch is to add an explicit check:

```
do {
    if ++diceRoll2 == 7 { diceRoll2 = 1 }
    square2 += diceRoll2
    if square2 < finalSquare {
        square2 += board2[square2]
    }
} while square2 < finalSquare
```

But it might be more readable if written in this form:

```
do {
    if ++diceRoll2 == 7 { diceRoll2 = 1 }
    square2 += diceRoll2
    if square2 < finalSquare {
        square2 += board2[square2]
    } else {
        break
    }
} while true
```

although I am not a big fan of endless loops with breaks inside.